# Apply CSS to all page except one specific page

Tags: html, css

The title says it all. I have a *Style.css* that apply properties to every `<Table>` on every page. I have 1 *SiteMap* page, on which i don't want to apply CSS for `<table>`. I tried this as a directive:

```
@page :not(:last) { }
```

It didn't work, besides i had to apply on any specif page, not the last one.

**Edited**
The table is auto-generating from XML file.

**Edited**
*SiteMap.aspx*

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" Runat="server" />

  <h3 id="Heading">SiteMap</h3>
  <br /><br />
  <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" Runat="Server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"  >
  </asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: Apply a special class to the excluded table and use that class with `:not()`. E.g. `table:not(.excluded) {}`

Comment: @ralph.m : The table is also autogerating.

Comment: Please show the source of your *SiteMap* HTML and an example of one of the other pages.

Comment: Are all the tables on the other pages auto-generated too, or just the one on your *SiteMap* page?

Comment: One on my *SiteMap* page.

Comment: Are you able to add a class to all the tables on the other pages?

Comment: No. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS to exclude the generated TreeView table, e.g.

```
table:not(#TreeView1) { ... }
```